# PHP shell_exec with a command does not behave the same way as when it is executed through the terminal

Tags: php, shell, command-line

When I execute the following command on the macOS 10.13 terminal:

```
curl 'https://api.perlego.com/metadata/v2/metadata/books/toc/682348' \
> -XGET \
> -H 'Origin: https://www.perlego.com' \
> -H 'Host: api.perlego.com' \
> -H 'Accept: application/json' \
> -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
> -H 'Accept-Language: en-sg' \
> -H 'Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate' \
> -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' \
> -H 'Referer: https://www.perlego.com/book/682348/10-human-how-your-bodys-microbes-hold-the-key-to-health-and-happiness-pdf' --compressed | brotli -d > temp.txt
```

This is the output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   535    0   535    0     0   1433      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1430
```

And I see a file temp.txt saved to the directory, with the data I need (a json).

But when I execute this through PHP:

```
$comd = <<<EOT
cd "/Users/user/Documents/RU_general"; curl 'https://api.perlego.com/metadata/v2/metadata/books/toc/682348' \
-XGET \
-H 'Origin: https://www.perlego.com' \
-H 'Host: api.perlego.com' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-sg' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' \
-H 'Referer: https://www.perlego.com/book/682348/10-human-how-your-bodys-microbes-hold-the-key-to-health-and-happiness-pdf' --compressed | brotli -d > temp.txt
EOT;

d($comd);
$res = shell_exec($comd); 

//***** exec() also results in the same problem
```

The file is still created, but the temp.txt file is blank.

What is going on, and how do I get the output I need?

Answer (score 1):

From a couple of tests I ran, this is related to the gzip compression. In your CURL request you ask the server for the compressed version, then decompress with `brotli`. Running your original `curl` code gives error on compression like `curl: (61) Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.`

My suggestion is to remove all compression information, remove `brotli` and just work with plain simple `json`. See below:

```
$comd = <<<EOT
cd "/Users/user/Documents/RU_general"; curl 'https://api.perlego.com/metadata/v2/metadata/books/toc/682348' \
-XGET \
-H 'Origin: https://www.perlego.com' \
-H 'Host: api.perlego.com' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-sg' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' \
-H 'Referer: https://www.perlego.com/book/682348/10-human-how-your-bodys-microbes-hold-the-key-to-health-and-happiness-pdf' > temp1.txt
EOT;
```

Moving forward, I recommend you to use the PHP Curl implementation instead of using the `shell_exec`. Not all hosting allow `shell_exec` and you're also blocked in case the hosting system doesn't offer `curl` or in your case even `brotli` which is not standard in Linux servers. Working with the PHP Curl allows you to stay within PHP and ensure your code is portable.